# SharePoint 2013 Central Admin Not Working

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have a strange issue with SharePoint 2013 CA is not working. The main problem is that the site simply will not load, it just sits there and spins. The second issue is that the times it does load which is rarely, it will randomly crash and log me out of the server completely to the windows login screen. I have checked that the app pool services are started. Questions I have:

1. Is there a way to repair/reinstall CA?
2. Has anyone seen something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot the issue as following:

1. Run SharePoint 2013 management Shell as administrator, then run the PowerShell command below to run a product wizard:

   PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install
2. [Clear SharePoint configuration cache](https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/clearing-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache/) and run IISREST.
3. If the issue exists, you can check the ULS log to get more error message about this issue based on the time when error occurred.

   ULS log is at: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS